# Error Uncaught out off memory when I use persisten object to save data on Blackberry?

Tags: blackberry-eclipse-plugin, persistent-storage

I use Persisten Object to save data but when I run my application on Simulator, have an error dialog

```
 Uncaught out off memory
```

and run on real device, it take very long time to load and run.
What did I do wrong? Please help me

Comment: please provide me how to store that persistent data in persistent memory i will check and i will give some solution

Answer (score 0):

The BlackBerry® Persistent Store APIs are designed to provide a flexible and robust data storage interface. With the BlackBerry Persistent Store APIs, you can save entire Java® objects to memory without having to serialize the data first. When you start the application, you can retrieve the Java object from memory and process the information. No size limit exists on a persistent store; however, the limit for an individual object within the store is 64 KB.

The BlackBerry Persistent Store APIs do not provide a relational database model. You must create an effective object model and manage the relationships between objects, as necessary, using indices and hash tables.

[sample example of storing persistent data](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Storing-persistent-data/ta-p/442747)

[best practice for persistent storage](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Best-Practices-for-Persistent-Store/ta-p/1154881)